# hide all elements with ID

Tags: javascript, html

I am wanting to hide all elements with the id=showhide

So I set my javascript as

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
</body>
```

and then my button as

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('showhide');">
                            <button>Show / Hide Details</button>
                            </a>
```

then I went and added the ID to a table, but it's only hiding the first instance of this ID, not all?

Comment: `id` are meant to be unique, instead use `class` for more than 1 element.

Comment: Buttons can't be descendants of links

Comment: For the time after the switch to `class` [javascript - What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like others have mentioned, you need to use a class instead of id. `getElementById` returns only one element while `getElementsByClassName` will return a collection of all elements ([`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)) with that class. I've attached a snippet showcasing how the code could look.

```js
function toggle_visibility(className) {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  for (const e of elements) {
    e.style.display = e.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle_visibility('showhide');">
  Show / Hide Details
</button>

<div class="showhide">A</div>
<div class="showhide">B</div>
<div class="showhide">C</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest ->  <button onclick="toggle_visibility('showhide');">Show / Hide Details</button>

Comment: Buttons can't be descendants of links

Comment: Agreed! Just copy pasted that part.

Comment: Note that what `document.getElementsByClassName` returns is technically **isn't** an Array. It's an array-like object, called `NodeList`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use id for this purposes. ID by it's ideology must be the SINGLUAR in your html.
You can for instance use classes and document.getElementsByClassName
Or you can use some specific attributes, whatever more convinient for you except ID's.